# Why myViewHolder(s) cannot be casted?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 ViewHolder in my `RecyclerViewAdapter` I used them to change the view depending on the position that I received dynamicaly.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        int viewType = 0;

        if (position == 0) {
            viewType = 0;
        }else if (position == 1){
            viewType = 1;
        }else if (position == 2){
            viewType = 2;
        }

        return viewType;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_notification, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        switch (viewType){
            case 0:
                return new MyViewHolder(v);
            case 1:
                return new MyViewHolderAccepted(v);
            case 2:
                return new MyViewHolderRefused(v);
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final DataNotifications dataNotifications = list.get(position);

    int type = Integer.valueOf(dataNotifications.getStatue());
    switch (getItemViewType(type)){
            case 0:
                MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                ........
                break;
            case 1:
                MyViewHolderAccepted myViewHolderAccepted = (MyViewHolderAccepted) holder;
                .......
                break;
            case 2:
                MyViewHolderRefused myViewHolderRefused = (MyViewHolderRefused) holder;
                ........
                break;
        }


//        Glide.with(context).load(dataNotifications.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumnail);




    }
```

When I run above code I got this exception :

> NotificationAdapter$MyViewHolder cannot be cast to 
>    NotificationAdapter$MyViewHolderAccepted

Should I have a different layout for each `ViewHolder` ? - But I only change a color of one `TextView`, so having layout for each `ViewHolder` would be expensive.

My viewHolders

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ....


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ....
        }
    }
     public class MyViewHolderAccepted extends MyViewHolder{
        ...

        public MyViewHolderAccepted(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ...
    }

    public class MyViewHolderRefused extends MyViewHolder{


        public MyViewHolderRefused(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: What id length of array you passing in array

Comment: downvoter can you explain why?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit which array ?

Comment: I mean in adapter.. or what your `getCount()` method returns?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit thanks for response it's worked now, check comments below

Answer (score 0):

> NotificationAdapter$MyViewHolder cannot be cast to NotificationAdapter$MyViewHolderAccepted

Most likely because it's `MyViewHolderAccepted` that extends `MyViewHolder` not the opposite. Or it does not extends it at all.

```
class MyViewHolderAccepted extends MyViewHolder {
   ....
```

**EDIT**

Note extends is NOT bidirectional. If class `B` extends `A`, then you can cast `B` to `A` but not `A` to `B` and this is what you are tying to do.

**EDIT 2**

> public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder

This. You need to change `holder` type in method signature to be `MyViewHolder`. Then it should be all fine.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it's throw the same error, i used one ViewHolder now and in my `onCreateViewHolder` i return `MyViewHolder` in three cases. now it's work.